# kate error: Unable to create KIO worker. Can not find a KIO worker for protocol "sftp"

Tags: 20.04, sftp, dolphin, kate

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and kate 23.08.4. For years I have been using dolphin to open files in kate over sftp using something like:

```
sftp://user.name@server/path/to/file.txt
```

in dolphin. However, I just started receiving these errors in kate when I try to open these files now:

```
Unable to create KIO worker. Can not find a KIO worker for protocol "tags".
Unable to create KIO worker. Can not find a KIO worker for protocol "sftp".
```

I'm not sure what changed. Maybe something got uninstalled? This is the kio stuff I currently have installed:

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep kio

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

kio-audiocd/focal,now 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kio-extras-data/focal,focal,now 4:19.12.3a-0ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
kio-extras/focal,now 4:19.12.3a-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kio-ldap/focal,now 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kio-sieve/focal,now 4:19.12.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
kio/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkf5kiocore5/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkf5kiofilewidgets5/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkf5kiogui5/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkf5kiontlm5/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libkf5kiowidgets5/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qml-module-org-kde-kio/focal,now 5.68.0-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Is something missing?

**UPDATE**
I discovered that I had 2 instances of Kate installed, one through apt, and one through snap. The snap one apparently is the one that was opening when I tried to open these files from dolphin. I uninstalled the snap one and reinstalled the apt one to make sure I had the latest version, and the error went away.

Is there a known bug with the snap version and sftp, or is it possible something wasn't configured correctly with the snap one, or maybe the 2 versions were conflicting with each other somehow?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer not as a question edit. Idk but snap breaks a lot of things by forcing a bunch of separations, especially tightly integrated things like KDE, in this case when your Kate app needed to connect to a KIO service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the update, the fix was to uninstall the snap version of kate, and reinstall the apt version of kate. The apt version of kate works with sftp with no errors.